# Authenticate AZURE Ad user by App role assigned to the user group

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have created an App role for my AZURE AD Backend Api and assigned this role to a group. Now I want to authenticate user in my .net core backend application on the basis if user has a group which has this role. I am getting the group ids in the access token but how can I get app roles assigned to these groups.

Comment: The roles should also come in the token as long as you are getting an access token for your backend API (with its client ID/App ID URI in scopes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check how you enabled group claims in Azure Portal.

If you check the Emit groups as role claims option like below you cannot see application roles, but you can see group ids.

[image]

**If the above option is enabled, make sure to uncheck the box.**

**[Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#customize-group-claim-name)**

> **If you use the option to emit group data as roles, only groups will
> appear in the role claim. Any application roles that the user is assigned to won't appear in the role claim.**

Also, I would suggest you refer to this Microsoft official documentation below which states that **if you add a service principal to a group, and then assign an app role to that group, Azure AD does not add the roles claim to tokens it issues.You can modify the “groupMembershipClaims”** field in application manifest if you want to include groups claim in your token like below: -

[Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#declare-roles-for-an-application)

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Configure group claims for applications by using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#customize-group-claim-name)